# How to solve the issue of unident does not match any outer indentation level in python?

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
  @client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    new_member = discord.Embed(description = f'{member} has joined the server',color=blue)
  print(embed = new_member):
```

**It is for my discord bot**
[image]
[image]

Comment: To solve indentation errors, you just need to indent the code correctly. General idea is 4 spaces indented to the right.

Comment: Why fo you have an assignment inside print? What are you expecting there?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
If you don't understand the error, it seems that you need to return to any tutorial on the meaning of indentation in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrect indentation, the : makes no sense there and I see no reason why you assign inside print.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    new_member = discord.Embed(description = f'{member} has joined the server',color=blue)
    print(new_member)
```

Comment: Yea i just started learn discord.py this ws day 1 and i was not watching any tutorials so i was confused. Looking back to my code it makes no sense, you cannot print a embed

Comment: @Sttencher it is usually good practice to mark answer that helped you as accepted. If none, then it is good to write your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 1):

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    new_member = discord.Embed(description = f'{member} has joined the server',color=blue)
```

For instance?

Regarding your `print()` I removed it. Cause I don't know how this can be used for.